# A non-standard ordinary differential equation: $\frac{d\left(xf\left(x\right)\right)}{dx}f(x)=\text{const}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this ODE?

$$\frac{d(xf(x))}{dx}f(x)=\text{const}.$$

It is clear that $f\left(x\right)=\text{const}$ is a solution but is it the only one? I don't need a formal proof just a good argument. A formal proof is also good though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation is $(xf)'f=A$ for some constant $A$. If $f=c$ then this says $c^2=A$, so the constant solutions are $f=\pm \sqrt A$.

Although the ODE is nonlinear, a simple trick reduces it to a simple linear ODE. Setting $g=xf$ and multiplying by $x$, the equation $(xf)'f=A$ becomes
$$ g'g = Ax \iff \frac12(g^2)'=Ax$$
Integrating gives the general solution
$$ g(x)^2 = Ax^2+c$$
i.e.
$$ f(x) = \pm\sqrt{A + \frac{c}{x^2}}$$
So the constant solutions are precisely those with $c=0$.